# My street is not showing up on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I type in my address and it does not show. Other people weren't able to bring it up either. Carl Sandburg Cir., Sacramento, California.

Are they changing the street name or something? I also do not know if any area besides our street is having issues.

Comment: How new is it? Map data isn't added instantly. It takes time. Can you find your cross street?

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, Google has mashed together the street name, so it is listed as "Carlsandburg Circle".  You can also find it by searching nearby cross streets.

Comment: I really think this question is too localized, but there's no good substitute in the new close reasons...

Comment: @jonsca - I'm torn. While it is a highly localised problem as stated the answer might be applicable to other people who's street names have been mangled in the same way.